# Parsing equations in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following expressions that I need to be able to parse into separate tokens:

```
"a=b+c"     ->  a b + c
"a=5+c"     ->  a 5 + c
"a=c*50"    ->  a c * 50
"a=50%50"   ->  a 50 % 50
"a=c-x[20]" ->  a c - x[20]
"a=x[3]+50" ->  a x[3] + 50
"a=b--c"    ->  a b - -c
```

I used [this regex help](https://txt2re.com/%20this%20regex%20help) but I can only apply the regex on one example, not all of them. For example, the following code would work only on "a=b+c","a=c-50" but not if I swap them into "a=c-50, "a=b+c":

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# URL that generated this code:
# http://txt2re.com/index-python.php3?s=%22a=b%2bc%22,%20%22a=c-50%22&-32&-34&25&-35&-33&36&27&5

import re

txt='"a=b+c", "a=c-50"'

re1='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re2='(a)'   # Any Single Character 1
re3='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re4='(b)'   # Any Single Character 2
re5='(.)'   # Any Single Character 3
re6='(c)'   # Any Single Character 4
re7='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re8='(a)'   # Any Single Character 5
re9='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re10='.'    # Uninteresting: c
re11='.*?'  # Non-greedy match on filler
re12='(.)'  # Any Single Character 6
re13='(.)'  # Any Single Character 7
re14='(\\d+)'   # Integer Number 1

rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12+re13+re14,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
   c1=m.group(1)
   c2=m.group(2)
   c3=m.group(3)
   c4=m.group(4)
   c5=m.group(5)
   c6=m.group(6)
   c7=m.group(7)
   int1=m.group(8)
   print("("+c1+")"+"("+c2+")"+"("+c3+")"+"("+c4+")"+"("+c5+")"+"("+c6+")"+"("+c7+")"+"("+int1+")"+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `re.split()`
It will split your equation on the basis of operators.
For example:

```
text = 'a=x[3]+50'
pattern = r'([\=\+\-\%\*])'
result = re.split(pattern, text)
```

Output:

```
['a', '=', 'x[3]', '+', '50']
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: How would you solve "a=b--c"    ->  a b - -c in this case?

Comment: @Gabriele Yes. It will work. Tryit.

Comment: It does not work, I get ['a', '=', 'b', '-', '', '-', 'c'] when it should be ['a', '=', 'b', '-', '-c']

Comment: Nevermind, found a work around with replace.